# Imitate service state in a different service when service stops/crashes

Tags: c#, msmq

I have two services which are hosted on two different servers.

Lets say, Service A on server A and Service B on server B. My service B is dependent on service A. I want to implement functionality like when Service B is crashed/stop explicitly (due to some reason), I want to Service A to imitate B so that Service A is stopped.

May I know how can I achieve this functionality?

**NOTE** : I have catches all the possible exception in my application but due to some DB problem or some unhandled exception (which didn't come during validation environment) I need to put this functionality.

Comment: Why do you want to introduce this functionality between services?

Comment: Look at ReliableSession.InactivityTimeout and ICommunicationObject.Faulted event

Answer (score 0):

you say that Service B is depended on Service A? so what happens if Service A stops working? does B also stop working, or does it just crash into on of the handled exceptions?

you could implement a `BackgroundWorker` within Service A which calls a specific function in Service B, and waits for a call back. if you put a `Thread.Sleep()` in the `DoWork` event of the `BackgroundWorker` you can have it run at set intervals. when the `backgroundWorker` does not get a return from the function you can then stop service A.

or you could use `WCF` with a `CallBack function` on Service B but that seems a bit overkill.

Comment: Service B is processing records which are sent by Service A, so its not important to stop service B when service A is crashed.  Is it work if both services are on different servers?

Comment: it depends if you can access the service B from outside e.i via a port or something similar.

Comment: however, other then WCF i do not know how to do it. WCF does a lot of things for you, especially in a simple implementation as this, but its some work to set up and it uses either an http/https/net.tcp port on both server A and B for communication. i wouldn't know how to access server B through a background worker without using some communication layer